# How many particles per acceleration cycle in a cyclotron?

Tags: acceleration

particle accelerators accelerate ''beams of particles'' - do cyclotrons accelerate single particles or a batch of particles per accelerating cycle? How many particles can be accelerated in a batch per one accelerating cycle by a cyclotron /bigger gap between dees?/

Comment: This question does not belong to space exploration, it belongs to physics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it "does not directly pertain to space exploration as outlined in the [help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)."

Comment: This question belongs on Physics.SE

Comment: Yes, in a cyclotron there are many "turns" of the outward spiral, usually between 100 and 1000 turns. Within each turn there are indeed short "bunches" or "batches". There will be a very simple relationship between the output current in units of particle-nanoamps to perhaps a few particle-microapms and the number of particles per bunch and the cyclotron frequency used. I hope your question can be quickly migrated to Physics SE.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I posted the question in Physics SE